# How to use newer versions of opencv in Fuerte

Tags: ros, opencv, cuda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently I had an issue building my own package depending on cv_bridge package and a custom-built opencv library. I was able to solve the linking problem in previous ROS versions [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/47249/problem-with-using-opencv_gpu-inside-ros/), but later I found out that the package was in fact using the fuerte/include/opencv header, but linking with the right /usr/local/lib libs. Everything should be OK if the headers were not changed, but if they do, it will fail.

To find out why I listed all the include dirs in cmake, and I got the following result(only the first 5 items)

```
-- --> include dir='/home/kai/Projects/my_pkg/include'
-- --> include dir='/opt/ros/fuerte/include'
-- --> include dir='/usr/local/include/opencv'
-- --> include dir='/usr/local/include'
-- --> include dir='/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include'
```

As can be seen, the ros/fuerte/include dir precedes the /usr/local/include; as a result, even if I can find my custom-built opencv headers and libraries through `FindPackage()` in CMakeLists.txt from setting the right $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH env var, the `#include <opencv.h>` will still find the `ros/fuerte/include/opencv` first.

To reproduce this problem, try the following:

1. Install ros fuerte opencv package
2. Download opencv from opencv.org and make&make install it with your own build options(namely, with CUDA)
3. Create a package depending on cv_bridge package
4. Follow the link provided above to make sure your CMakeLists.txt can use `FindPackage()` to find your custom built opencv package(default in /usr/local)
5. Write some pieces of code using opencv's specific features(CUDA, if you built with it)
6. `rosmake` or `cmake ..& make` it.
7. Check the depend.make file under your_pkg/build/CMakeFiles/your_pkg.dir, find opencv occurrences, it will be `/opt/ros/fuerte/include/opencv`, not `/usr/local/include/opencv`

So what I am writing to ask is, is there any way to make my own opencv include path precedes the ros include path? Or it won't be found because there is a opencv/opencv2 dir in the `fuerte/include` dir and they will be found first. Currently I renamed ROS's provided opencv&opencv2 dirs names to hide them from being found, but I think there should be some better way.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61923/how-to-use-newer-versions-of-opencv-in-fuerte/) by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 391 on 2013-05-01

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on 2013-05-01**:
And, I am under ubuntu 12.04 32-bit. No catkin build or ros_ws(still uses the old fashioned $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cheated and went to /opt/ros/fuerte/include and changed the name of opencv2 to opencv2bak.
This way it finds the right includes.
I don't think it's the right way to do it, though.

Also, went to /opt/ros/fuerte/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake and edited the Install path variable to /usr/local (where I installed)

---

Originally posted by [DiogoRolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4611/diogorolo/) with karma: 56 on 2013-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on 2013-05-24**:
Yes, this is what I am doing right now, but this would be overwritten when it updates, so I am asking for some more "elegant" way

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-05-12**:
We should always note for future reference that modifying protected location like under `/opt` isn't recommended.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem. The thing is ros sets CPATH variable to something like:

```
/home/jep/catkin_ws/devel/include:/opt/ros/groovy/include
```

Then when compiling gcc always finds ROS opencv headers instead of the new ones...
So I ended up just deleting CPATH whenever I need to compile somthing with the new OpenCV version.

---

Originally posted by [Jep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2367/jep/) with karma: 195 on 2014-02-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1